# How to change the duration of vibration in iOS / Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-vibrate

It's possible to make the device vibrate with `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))`. But is there also a way to set the duration of the vibration process? I want it to be shorter.

I thought of stopping the vibration before it fully finishes, e.g. after 0.05 seconds. Is this possible?

Comment: This link gives you the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios. Basically, you can make custom vibration yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like Apple is rejecting custom vibration patterns?

Comment: Yay, I would imagine so. If you use any undocumented API, it is likely that Apple would reject it.

Comment: For short vibration durations, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44495798/2186887